# How to write join queries in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables `posts` and `users`. The `post.user_id=users.id`.

The fields are

```
user: id, username, password
post: id, user_id, post_name
```

I would like to `select post.id, post.post_name, user.username`.

How to select this in CakePHP?

I have two Models named `User` and `Post`. It calls the Model from `PostController`.

Comment: the two models have no relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should properly define the relations between the two models in order to simplify your life, but if you want to use a join, here is the syntax:

```
find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('name' => 'Thomas Anderson'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'Thought',
                'table' => 'thoughts',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => '`Thought`.`person_id` = `Person`.`id`'
            )
        )
 ));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have [correctly defined the relationship between those two models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), this should just happen when you use the Post model's find method:

```
// In PostsController
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');

// $posts should be an array like this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                    // Model data
                )
            [User] => Array
                (
                    // Model data
                )
        )
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the two models have no relation